# SQL Query- How to find the difference from last week of last year and first week of current year

Tags: sql-server

I am joining some three tables and getting the following values
`week_num` `provision` difference

```
1          34234
2          4583
```

i need to find the difference between the provision for `week_num2-provision` for `week_num1` similarly provision for `week_num1-provision` for `week_num52` of last year.
Since i have given condition to bring only 2012 data i donno how to bring the 2011 last week data into this table and find the difference. 
can anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: Can you show us some table structure?

Comment: That should be easy, given you can derive year and wekk number from your data. Can't really help you without the table definitions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the DATEDIFF function to compute the difference between dates in SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx.

It would help if you could provide a simplified schema in order to guide you to the actual query you need.